# Change operator color in sublime text?

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, sublimetext2

In notepad ++ I can change the color of special characters like "!@#$%^&*(){}[].

Is this possible with sublime text ? I know it uses textmate theme files, but I don't know what I should edit...

Any idea ?

PS: I mostly use C++ syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that operators are not listed in Sublime Text's C++ language file, so I think you need to add them first.

To the file *%SUBLIMEDIR% / Packages / C++.sublime-package / C++.tmLanguage* add the following:

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\=|\+|\-|\*|\%|\+\+|\-\-|\=\=|\!\=|&lt;|&gt;|&lt;\=|&gt;\=|\!|&amp;&amp;|\|\||\~|&amp;|\||\^|&lt;lt;|&gt;&gt;|\+\=|\-\=|\*\=|/\=|\%\=|&amp;\=|\|\=|\^\=|&lt;&lt;\=|&gt;&gt;\=|\[|\]|\(|\)|\-&gt;|\-&gt;\*|\.|\.\*|\?|\:|\:\:</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.operator</string>
</dict>
```

...in the region where similar entries are being made. That should cover most C++ operators.

Afterwards the edit suggested by Protractor Ninja should take effect. I haven't thoroughly tested this though, a sophisticated regex might be better.

Comment: seems there are html character syntax things, I'll try this later

Comment: If you mean **&lt;**, **&gt;** and **&amp;**, those are just aliases for **<**, **>** and **&**. I have already discovered that the regex I posted doesn't work in all cases (e.g. function parentheses). I will learn about regex now, which is new to me, and see if I can come up with a more robust solution. I wish Sublime Text had all the bases covered out of the box; it's not like C++ is a fringe language.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a tad late, but to change operator color in Sublime Text, you'll have to edit your color scheme file (`.tmTheme` filetype). As long as the language definition for the language you're using is written in such a way that the symbols you want are classified as operators, this ought to do the trick.

Add the following code to the end of your current `.tmTheme` file (located in `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/` if you're using one of the defaults; others will be either in their own subdirectory or in `Packages/User/`), just before the final `</array>` tag:

```
<!-- Custom operator colors -->
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Custom Operator Colors</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>keyword.operator</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <!-- Your hexadecimal color code here -->
        <string>#FFFFFF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

That will colorize code categorized as `keyword.operator` (based on the [TextMate naming conventions](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#naming_conventions)) with whatever color value you desire. This solution will hold for all languages, as long as you use the same color scheme.